# Why do I get this error when attempting to generics to implement a custom ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am attempting to implement an sub class that extends ArrayList. This class should print the elements of an array.

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class MyArrayList <T extends ArrayList> {
    public void  display (MyArrayList<T> processList) {
        for (T element : processList) {

        }
    }
}
```

However this code gives me the error:
foreach not applicable to type 'MyArrayList'

I'm not sure why?

I tried making the parameter type a wildcard however this did not resolve the issue.
EDIT: This class is extending ArrayList and the full class is shown (although for some reason the "public class MyArrayList " does not seem to be showing properly. The error is specific the for loop for 'processList'.

Comment: Probably because `MyArrayList` does not implement `Iterable<T>`.  Without showing the code for `MyArrayList` nobody can help you.

Comment: You class does not extend `ArrayList`. In order to provide the possibility to use instances of your class in a `foreach`-loop, the class must implement the [`Iterable` interface (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyArrayList <T extends ArrayList> {
```

That does not mean your class extends arraylist.

That means your class says: For every type reference of this type (such as when you declare a method that accepts a `MyArrayList`, or you make a variable of type `MyArrayList` - any time you mention 'MyArrayList', the type), there is a type parameter. It means - whatever you want it to mean (generally for lists one would think it means: "The type of the thing I am meant to hold" - that's what it means with `java.util.ArrayList` - an `ArrayList<String>` is an array list that holds string objects).

Specifically, we shall call that type, whatever it happens to be, 'T', and we shall also restrict it: It must be either `ArrayList` or some subtype of it. Specifically, the raw arraylist type (you really don't want that).

In other words, it says whenever somebody *uses* this class, their choice of T must extend ArrayList.

Type variables do nothing on their own. You've just declared that any use of your type will mean the user picks some type T. Okay. If you do nothing with it, that's not going to mean anything.

Presumably what you're looking for is this:

```
public class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {}
```

This says:

- Anytime `MyArrayList` is used as a type, the user must pick some type which we shall call 'T'; each use picks their own T, so we don't know what T is - we write code for **all** users, so, T is everything all at once. It's a meta-type.
- We extend `ArrayList`. Hey - we are **using** ArrayList as a type, and ArrayList demands we pick a type!
- We pick 'T'. Our T. Note that the syntax is identical (`<T>` in both cases), but they represent different things. The first `<T>` *declares a type variable*. The second `<T>` uses it. We say that our class extends `ArrayList<T>` where T is whatever the user of our class picked.

Your class would now extend `ArrayList`, and `ArrayList`, in turn, implements `Iterable<T>`. You must implement Iterable if you want an expression of your type to be usable in the 'collection' position in `for (SomeType variableName : collection) {}`. Your snippet doesn't (it doesn't extend anything - only its T does which has no effect on your own type) - with this fix, it does.